# Android storage with UTC timestamps?

Tags: mount, time-zones

I would like to use UTC timestamps on the FAT partition on my Android phone.

Reason:

When one moves files from an Android phone to a Linux desktop, one gets wrong timestamps for files which were modified during daylight saving time. The FAT driver on Linux converts the local timestamps from the FAT partition to UTC timestamps on the desktop. It cannot handle daylight saving time, though.

There is an option `tz=UTC` to `mount` on Linux to skip this conversion, i.e. to assume that the timestamps were in UTC on the FAT partition.

Consequently, a way to get around the problem would be to use a similar option on Android to use UTC timestamps on the Android storage.
Is that possible?